Batch Importing SharePoint List into Azure Data Factory Where number of rows > 5000
I have setup an adf pipeline that pulls from a SharePoint online list copies this to blob storage and then from there it is copied to a sql server database table. This works but I need to pull back more than the 5k row limit. I'm aware this can be done in batches (stackoverflow answer) but I can't find any instructions online on how to do this (which I understand). I've read through this article SharePoint REST API batching - exploring batch payloads but I don't understand how to incorporate this in adf.

What blocker you are facing. Please add what you tried and error/blockers you got.

Thank you. Sorry I haven't tried anything as I don't understand how to implement it at all.
